# Preferred solution to extend on an existing AuthenticationScheme in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, windows-authentication

I am trying to integrate a very simple authentication scheme that essentially breaks down to:

- Authenticate the user using Windows Authentication;
- Ensure the user's AD name is present in a database and fetch his internal ID to add it as a claim.

My first approach looks somewhat like this:

- Add the default negotiate authentication scheme through the service builder;
- Configure a middleware that is called in between `UseAuthentication()` and `UseAuthorization()`
  and looks for the required ID to add; it interrupts the pipeline with a 401 if unsuccessful.

Though this technically works I was thinking that the cleaner solution would be to treat the ID resolving as part of the Scheme itself without the need to include a middleware as well.

Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps by inheriting from the AuthenticationHandler used by `Negotiate`? The result should look something like this:

```
  services.AddAuthentication(MyCustomNegotiateAuthenticationScheme.Name)
            .AddCustomNegotiate();
```

Now there should be no additional middleware required, just a call to

```
UseAuthentication()
```

(The scheme provided in `DefaultIdentity` does ssomething similar, it just takes the service configuration and desired claims are included from the cookie.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into the auth scheme's events. You can there manipulate the principal and also the auth flow. (The events usually use a Func which returns a Task, so you can use async-await there.)

For example with cookie auth you can do the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(options => 
    {
        options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = context => { your logic goes here... }
    });
```

Another approach could be creating custom implementation for one of these classes:

- [UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser,>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userclaimsprincipalfactory-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
- [UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser,TRole>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.userclaimsprincipalfactory-2?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

In this approach I would inherit from one of them and I would try overriding one of the (protected or public) methods. You can find it's current implementation [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserClaimsPrincipalFactory.cs).

Comment: Though this somewhat goes into the direction I was seeking to, there seems to be no equivalent to this for the Negotiate scheme. I am looking for a straightforward but solid approach specifically for that scheme. After all, my current approach can be broken down to an additional 10 line middleware.